# Spark all jobs have been completed. but application still running

Tags: apache-spark

All jobs of my Spark task have been executed, but the saprkcontext cannot be stop.
[image]

The following is the dirver log:
[image]

This doesn't happen every time, about one of 10 runs fails to end the application.

i use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool().submit()` to process About 500 SQL statements

Comment: Just a quick question. Are you writing this on S3?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim I have the same issue, I am writing this on obs, which is like s3, pretty much and all tasks have been finished, yet this application is still running. What about s3? Does it have this kind of problem? I noticed that on obs, there's a "spark-staging" hidden directory, which has all the output files, after the job has been running for 4 hours, but the output directory has no files yet... Do you know anything about that also?

Comment: This question I have asked about S3 because the old hadoop filesystem configuration for S3 had a problem. After all the transformations are finished the Spark to S3 using hadoopfilesystem would create a temp folder in S3 during the transformation. And after that would copy from the temp folder back to the final folder. That would take. a lot of time if you had too many files in S3. Today the new S3 SDK of spark doesn't do that anymore.